# Type mismatch in VBA code expiry date check

Tags: excel, vba, date, type-mismatch

Im trying to use this cod for checking expiry date. Im using Code before to open different file and copy cells as below. Please can any one help why I have Run time Error 13 Type mismatch. Any ideas ??
I was trying to put If empty cell exit sub but still that same :(

```
    Set wkbData = Workbooks.Open(Filename, , True)
    wkbData.Sheets("IBL").Range("H1:I100").Cells.Copy
    wkbSource.Sheets("Expiry Date").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wkbData.Close
    Dim LRow As Integer
    Dim LResponse As Integer
    Dim LName As String
    Dim LDiff As Integer
    Dim LDays As Integer
    LRow = 2
    LDays = 31
    While LRow < 200
        If Len(Sheets("Expiry Date").Range("A" & LRow).Value) > 0 Then
            If Len(Sheets("Expiry Date").Range("A" & LRow).Value) = "" Then Exit Sub
                LDiff = DateDiff("d", Date, Sheets("Expiry Date").Range("A" & LRow).Value)
                If (LDiff > 0) And (LDiff <= LDays) Then
                    LName = Sheets("Expiry Date").Range("B" & LRow).Value
                    LResponse = MsgBox("The Juice " & LName & " will expire in " & LDiff & " days.", vbCritical, "Warning")
                End If
            End If
            LRow = LRow + 1
            Worksheets(1).Activate
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Could be your `Len(...=""` line. the Len() function returns an int and you are comparing it to a string. Could also be a bad date  in your "Expiry Date" sheet. This may cause the DateDiff function to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive that this is the exact problem but I think that your syntax on DateDiff may be off.  I understand it should look something like this:  DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Now, Sheets("Expiry Date").Range("A" & LRow).Value)

Answer (score 0):

Yes  Myles and Luke

But Luke comment was right. I don't know why but excel change one of the dates format what cause this issue. Now its ok.

Thank you for support now its working perfectly. I will try to find code to If date wrong change for..

Thanks for help with this.